# MS Excel Column content replication across two sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Microsoft Excel functional Question

How do I replicate (copy a column contents of Values to another sheet column) of a whole column (with data content) from a primary sheet to an secondary sheet in another column?

When primary sheet is updated (populated with data) the values of replicated column are automatically updated in the column of the other sheet?

I expected a Hyperlink function without specifying single cell replications by reference!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data are in (primary) *Sheet1!A* column and your replica is *Sheet2!A* column. So you just enter `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1)), Sheet1!A1, "")` in cell a1 and then copy it to remaining cells. 
Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

This would be something that could be accomplished in **Microsoft Excel** using a custom [macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/training/meet-macros-RZ001150634.aspx?section=2) ("...bits of code stored in the workbook that can automate repetitive tasks and quickly get your data in order."), I will attempt to break the problem down, provide a usable solution and after some housekeeping, instructions on how to use it.

### The Problem

Let's break the problem down using arbitrary `Sheet` and `Column` names:

- We are given two worksheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`
- Contained in `Sheet1` are values stored on `Column A`
- Contained in `Sheet2` we have `Column B` which may or may not contain values
- We want *all* changes made to `Sheet1`:`Column A` to *automatically* copy themselves to `Sheet2`:`Column B`

### The Solution

By creating a macro that is triggered by `Worksheet_Change` we can have the macro automatically copy the values over, I will explain how this works afterwards:

```
' I have included some brief comments to help understand what is going on
' Automatically triggers when a change to a cell(s) occurs on the Sheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Target is an object, it also tells us where the change occurred

    ' Did the change occur in column A (A = 1, B = 2, etc)?
    If (Target.Column = 1) Then
        ' Get the ROW of where the change occurred
        Dim row as Integer = Target.Row

        ' Update Sheet2 using our row, but use column B
        Sheet2.Cells(row, "B") = Target.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

### Housekeeping

*Please* remember:

- Macros such as the one I have written above will generally only work in **Microsoft Excel**
- Macros are often means for transmission of **computer viruses** and caution should be taken that you do not enable any and/or run macros from untrusted sources - that being said **if you choose to use any of the instructions I have provided you do so at your own risk**
- Macros reside inside the workbook (spreadsheet) in which you write them, and are saved every time you save normally; however:
- In modern versions of Excel you may need to save your workbook as a different file-type (Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook .xlsm) for the above to hold
- Unless you digitally sign a macro (outside of the scope of this guide), you may need to enable the macro to run every time you load the workbook

### How-To

To begin adding this macro to your workbook you need to load first have the spreadsheet open that you want to use, then launch **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications** (referred onwards as VBA) using the keys `Alt + F11`.

(At this point I would maximize the VBA window to avoid confusion and possible distractions)

With the VBA window active you will see on the left side a small interior window labelled

`Project - VBAProject`

This usually contains the project hierarchy, and it is where we can add macros to our workbook. The place we want to add our macro is `Sheet1 (Sheet1)`.

`Sheet1 (Sheet1)` is an `object` called `Sheet1` which is a programming representation of the worksheet. You can see the name you would of the worksheet you would normally edit in excel contained within the parentheses, in this case it is also called Sheet1.

To add a macro to `Sheet1` you can either `right-click` and then click `View Code` or simply double-click it to open it in the `Code` window.

From here you can copy-and-paste my solution to get going.

If you would like to write macros yourself, I would recommend you go through the link on the first page, as well as read the [Introduction to custom macros in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/introduction-to-custom-macros-in-excel-HA001118958.aspx).

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution, Will try it.. :) JJ